# I need to use JavaScript to change mailto: href links to new email domains

Tags: javascript, html

At work, we have a very old ASP.Net site and on our page that shows who to contact, there are a bunch of `<a>` tags with `mailto:` links on them for emails for the different departments.

Since this site was built a long time ago, we don't want to try to open it in Visual Studio and go changing things for fear of messing something up, as the site still works very good for its purpose. It was written in Visual Studio .NET 2003 and we just don't want to chance it. We don't even own any copies of VS that old anymore. All our stuff now is written using Visual Studio 2013 and up.

So with that being said, I noticed that when I did a view source on this particular page is linking to a JavaScript file called `clmenu.js` or something like that. So I thought I'd just open that JS file and add a little code at the top to change all the links to the new domain. So all the links on the page are like this

```
<a href="mailto:whateverdepartment@olddomain.com">whateverdepartment@olddomain.com</a>
```

and I need to change the links to this:

```
<a href="mailto:whateverdepartment@newdomain.com">whateverdepartment@newdomain.com</a>
```

Is it possible using JavaScript to change just the @olddomain.com to @newdomain.com on all of these links? I have to use plain old JavaScript, not jQuery; as jQuery was not used on this site.

Comment: Sure that's possible, but SO isn't a code-writing service.

Comment: @jonrsharpe, I appreciate your reply, but I'm not asking anybody on SO to write anything for me. I simply didn't know where to start with this particular situation. Believe me, I had already tried some things before I EVER got on here. I'm the type of guy that will try to no end to do something on my own before ever asking ANYBODY for help. I see developers on here all the time that are asking for help for a particular situation that, I'm sure, have already tried on their own first. I've done many things in life, but being a JavaScript guru is not one to them. Have a good day.

Comment: So you did already try something? Then give a [mcve]. If you literally didn't know where to start, you weren't ready for SO.

Comment: I did @jonrsharpe, I tried the other day, but I can't remember what I did. Believe me, I will try all sorts of things before I jump on here. I only use SO as a last resort.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are probably better ways of doing this, but this should help you with *most* cases:

```js
document.querySelectorAll('a[href^="mailto:"][href$="olddomain.com"]') // match all links beginning with "mailto" and ending with "olddomain.com"
  .forEach(e => {
    e.href = e.href.split("@")[0] + "@newdomain.com"; // split the string into an array without the @ sign and put it back together 
    e.innerHTML = e.innerHTML.split("@")[0] + "@newdomain.com"; // do the same here
  });
```

```html
<a href="mailto:somedep@olddomain.com">somedep@olddomain.com</a><br>
<a href="mailto:somedep2@olddomain.com">somedep2@olddomain.com</a><br>
<a href="mailto:anotherdep@anothercompany.com">anotherdep@anothercompany.com</a>
```

Comment: Ok thank you @Luca, I'll give this a try. I'm currently working on another project at the moment, but that worked GREAT when I navigated to that page in Firefox, hit F12 and put it in the debugger. Thanks man.

Comment: Would you mind marking the question as answered then? :)

Comment: Sure, sorry about that. (-: